# Difference between Ito calculus and Malliavin calculus

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, malliavin-calculus

Is there some difference between Ito calculus and Malliavin calculus ? 
  I can't find a comparison ito vs malliavin essay on the web . 
I am thankful if someone describe the difference or guide to a paper that include a comparison.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Ito calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus) extends the methods of classical calculus to stochastic functions of random variables.

The [Malliavin calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malliavin_calculus) extends the classical [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) to stochastic functions. Just as the variational calculus allows considering derivatives in infinite dimensional function space, the Malliavin calculus extends stochastic analysis to infinite dimensional space.

In other words, I think the analogy between the Ito and Malliavin calculi is the same as that between the classical multivariable calculus and the variational calculus.

Check out [this work by Han Zhang](http://frank-oertel-math.de/PhD_thesis_on_Malliavin_Calculus_incl_copy_of_FO.pdf), which has an introductory description of both.

Answer (score 6):

There is one important fact which shows a connection but also where things differ.

Ito's integral exists for integrands **adapted** to the filtration of Brownian motion. In Malliavin calculus you define the Malliavin derivative, $D$ and it's adjoint $\delta$, which is called the Skorokhod integral.

Neat fact: if $f$ is adapted to the filtration of Brownian motion, then $\delta(f)=\int f dW_s$, the Ito integral. If $f$ is not adapted, then $\delta(f)$ can still make sense even though $\int f dW_s$ doesn't.

So one really important difference is that you can integrate non adapted integrands.